# Angular 6 GeoFire Initialization GeoFire is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, geofire

[image]I am having problem initializing GeoFire on Angular 6. When I tried to initialize GeoFire,

> geofire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a constructor

error is thrown.

Below are my dependencies and code.

```
"@angular": "6.0.2",
"firebase": "5.0.3",
"geofire": "4.1.2",
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9"
"typescript": "2.7.2"

import * as GeoFire from 'geofire';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
@Component({
    selector: 'app-near-by-page',
    templateUrl: './near-by-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./near-by-page.component.scss']
})
export class NearByPageComponent extends PageComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // Generate a random Firebase location
        const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('locations');

        // Create a new GeoFire instance at the random Firebase location
        const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
        const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
            center: [51.294, -0.245],
            radius: 1
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Import**

> const geofire = require('geofire');

**Usage**

> const geoFireInstance = new geofire.GeoFire(ref);

source: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/issues/173#issuecomment-487026534

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a known issue. The codebase for `geofire` has been updated to resolve this issue however a new build has not been deployed to npm.

You could install straight from GitHub though with `npm i firebase/geofire-js`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to import it afterwards ? import * as GeoFire from "geofire"; throws an error for me.